# How do I include a JavaScript variable in an HTML header?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in HTML and JavaScript and I don't know how to include a Javascript variable in an HTML header.
The question is how to define variables in the `header` of HTML and use them in the `body`.
For instance,

```
for (var i in array)
{
  var num = i;
  var customForm = '<form> \
                    <h2>***INCLUDE NUM VARIABLE HERE***</h2> \
                    </form>';
}
```

Comment: Reopen the question, problems of clarity have been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

```
var customForm = '<form> \
                    <h2>' + num + '</h2> \
                  </form>';
```

or

```
var customForm = `<form> \
                    <h2>${num}</h2> \
                  </form>`
```

The first one just concats the variable into the string, the second one is template literal (template string) from **ES6**, and you must use these **`** backquotes.

Comment: Then you will do something like innerHTML to change the HTML of the page.

Comment: the second one works thanks

Comment: I see why the first one doesn't I used " instead of  ', it's edited now it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this example:

```js
var example = "<h1> A title in JS </h1>";

function changeContent()
{
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = example;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>

<button onClick="changeContent()">Click to change content</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

For any javascript beginners, I think a more detailed answer than the accepted response would be beneficial. The question essentially asks how to insert dynamic, javascript-generated content into html, which is a very common use case. The most common approaches are concatenation and template literals.

**Concatenation:**

```
var customFormHead = '<form> \
                    <h2>';
var customFormTail = '</h2> \
                    </form>';
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  myhtml = customFormHead + array[i] + customFormTail;
}
```

This solution uses concatenation to build the final string. Concatenation is a very important concept for beginning coders to learn. My example also changes the user supplied example so that the for loop is written in correct javascript syntax.

**Template Literals:**

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var customForm = `<form> \
               <h2>${i}</h2> \
              </form>`
}
```

Template literals are considered better than concatenation for several use cases. In this case, a template literal would be easier to code and easier to read/edit later. Template literals can also be used to insert the result of raw javascript code (not just variables) into a string, so

```
var customForm=`<form><h2>${document.getElementById("myDiv")}</h2></form>`
```

would work as long as your html has an element with an id equal to "myDiv".

```
var customForm=`<form><h2>${variable}</h2></form>`
```

This is very useful because you could write a whole html page using template literals and then fill in the values based on a user's actions.

**Note** that using template literals requires tick marks instead of quotation marks and the beginning and end of your string.

Answer (score 0):

If you had an `h1` that looked like this:

```
<h1 id='myHeader'></h1>
```

Your JavaScript could put a variable in there using the `.textContent` property like this:

```
document.getElementById("myHeader").textContent = myVariable
```

This line selects the `h1` using it's `id` and updates its textContent.